# OP amp PI controlled electrical load

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation, pid-controller, load, current-sink

I am building an electrical load, capable of "sinking" 0 - 3A on a maximum of 60VDC. I want to control the load with a microcontrollers ADC (0-3V). On the internet you find hundereds of circuit propositions, that build around bipolar transistors or FET. I chose a design with a NMOS FET as actual sink.
The circuits principally work - but a FET is a capacitive load. So the circuit I built (following an article on design ideas (google "Power-MOSFET-is-core-of-regulated-dc-electronic-load") is oscillating.
I need my design to be as failsafe as possible. Merging all information I have I ended with this [image: Circuit] around a PowerFET and a PI control loop.
I started by a simulation with TINA-TI. But I have some doubts about the results:
[image: Diagram 1]

- Why do I have this huge Peak in the beginning of a transient analysis (Zero initial values)?
- The current sense IC INA168 should provide a linear output tension - why do I have 72mA flowing after a step response of 500mV, 3.4A after 3V and nothing useful after 50mV?
- Is it normal that the OP Amps are staying at -VCC with 0V input? shouldnt the have 0V at the output aswell?
- Does this transient analyses make sense at all? Which other analysis should I perform?

Unfortunately stackexchange doesn't let me post more than 2 links, so I cannot post the other simulation results.

Comment: The article you refer to has a much straightforward feedback loop. Your feedback has the INA168 followed by 5 stages of opamps ! Can you simplify this ? Each opamp adds a delay, an it becomes much more difficult to stabilize.

Comment: I have seen much simpler circuits for PI controller, you can put almost everything in one single opamp.

Comment: I am aware that I went much further with my circuit, mainly because I ended with an oscillating circuit and had no idea why. So I started from scratch with a circuit where I can individually adjust Ki and Kp. I guess I can simplify as soon as I have the desired output - when I know what my parameters have to be. I hope to be able to replace U2, U3, U7 and U6 by [this](http://rn-wissen.de/wiki/images/0/05/Analogregler.png). U5 and R9 guarantee me the stability into my capacitive load and U4 buffers my INA.

Comment: You might try slowing down the "process" by adding a capacitor from gate to drain, starting with 10 nF and increase as necessary.  You may also increase the value of R9 at the same time. Also I would simulate with an AC source in series with R9 and run AC sweep before running transient sim.

Comment: @scorpdaddy I added the capacitor so my resulting circuit is as [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13255863/ans2_sch1.png) What is this exactly doing? I have a 10nF D --> G now in series with 2.8nF G --> S. Then I wanted to add the voltage generator after R9 - but as soon as I try to run AC analysis it complains that only one input source is allowed. Should I remove VG1?

Comment: Look at that schematic, don't see a cap from gate to drain.  But a cap from gate to drain couples changes and AC from drain to to gate with negative feedback.  So that slows down drain voltage changes, limits AC bandwidth of FET.

Comment: @scorpdaddy sorry, here we go: [schematics](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13255863/ans1_sch2.png) I copied the wrong link... but I guess I will merge your and WhatRoughBeasts answer to a final circuit I will publish. Thanks for all your inputs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merging the two answers I ended with the following design, that doesn't show the unwanted oscillations. [image: Circuit]

Answer (score 1):

So the first thing is to decide on an accuracy on the current that one can live with, as this sets other parameters.  So lets say 0.03A, or 1% of full scale.

Next, let's define the process we want to control as the circuit from Vgate(Vfet in the schematic) through U4-output. Lets call that Vout.  Checking the fet datasheet, the gain given is 13 A/V, although perhaps less depending on actual bias point in the application. Sense resistor 0.01ohm.  INA168 setup for 75V/V gain. U4 unity buffer.  Total process DC gain 13*0.01*75*1 = roughly 10 V/V.
And the error at Vout will be 22.5mV for a 30 mA current error.

The input at Vgate will be somewhere in the 2-10 V range, say nominally 5 V.  Vgate-nominal / Vout-errorlimit roughly equal to total open-loop gain for appreciable gain >> 1.  So minimum open loop gain required about 5V/.0225V = 222 V/V.  The "process" provides a gain of about 10 V/V above, so control loop gain minimum about 22.

The control circuit above (from Vout, aka U4-output) to Vgate has 4.7 V/V gain at frequencies above 3.4kHz, and unlimited gain at DC, well limited only by the internal gain of U7, which could be 1000V/V or more. That may be super accurate in terms of output error, sort of, but can be challenging for stability.  If one is using 1% resistors, then there is already 1% error at R2 and one wonders why one would need more than that from the accompanying control circuit.

Right off the top you could remove R12 and change R8 for a 470k - and probably get ok results.  The open loop gain in the control circuit would be 47, which meets our minimum of 22.  And taking out the very high gain from U7 might settle the circuit down enough to be stable right there.

If you had to put more DC gain in, you could put a resistor in parallel with C1 to limit the DC gain to something reasonable like 100, eg a 1000k in parallel with C1.  But you may not need it if the 470k for R8 above got you acceptable results.

In terms of the accuracy you need: this circuit is driven by a micro+DAC. Ok, perhaps a calibration could be stored in the micro to correct a small %age error in the analog circuit.  You might be able to live with more than 1% FS for the error in such case because the micro can correct for that.

In terms of the number of opamps, it is possible to provide the function needed with less micros.  From the circuit above I would retain the unity buffer U4.  A similar unity buffer is perhaps required on the DAC output.  A 20k input impedance may be too much for the DAC output.  A third opamp can produce Vgate from the 2 buffered signals.  But unless you are tight for cost or board area then the circuit above is ok.

In terms of the simulation, you can put a AC frequency sweep voltage source IN SERIES with R9.  Then look at the signal out U5-output that results from the series AC voltage source.  Check the gain and phase margin through the process and control loop combined to ensure a robust, stable control.

Comment: Such an elaborate answer. I still dont fully understand how you ended with this open- and closed loop gain - but I get the overall point. So after removing R12 and changing R8 to 470k I get the follwing [output](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13255863/ans_1.png). I added R13 and ended up with the follwing [schematics](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13255863/ans_sch.png) and [output](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13255863/ans_2.png). Do you have any idea what happened here? The erroranalysis is also very important and will be considered soon!

Comment: what came into my mind: changing R8 into 470k would change my Kp from initially 4.7 to 47 (Ki =1000). I tried to adjust the circuit with an empirical method, raising Kp slowly up to constant oscialltions (happening at about Kp=10) and then calculating Kp = 0.45*Kpcritical. How would this be possible to fulfill the requirements of Kp AND open loop gain?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot speak to everything in your circuit, but a few things jump out.

1) There is absolutely no need to use +/- 36 volts for your op amps. The final output, to the gate of the FET, only needs to swing a few volts above ground to turn on the FET. Futhermore, if you get negative loop saturation (as you have done) your gate drive of ~-35 volts will destroy the op amp.

2) There is no obvious need to use a high-side current sensor, unless you are driving a grounded load. Put your shunt resistor to ground, and use a simple inverting amp to both buffer the voltage and give you your gain (since you are using a very small shunt resistor).

3) Unless you have something peculiar going on (are you trying to provide 0 to 3 amps for a 0 to 2.5 volt input, perhaps?) your choice of 300k on the sensor output seems odd.

4) Since your P and I term generators are both inverters, you can greatly simplify your circuit topology.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIN00s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you feel you must use a higher supply voltage for the op amps, I've added D1 as protection.

In general, I'd expect that your turn-on transients are caused by integrator windup. Try simulating with a power-on ramp from zero to your desired voltage. Additionally, your questionable voltages and currents are 1)partly due to your choice of 300k, and 2) offset voltages in the op amps.

Comment: 1) You are right - there is no need to drive the OP Amps with +-36V - it was a leftover from when I tried finding the correct Kp and Ki and needed higher rail supplys. I changed it back, in the same time I changed them into controlled voltage source, adding a ramp `0,0
1u,12
1,12`
2)I am testing a battery / powersupply, so I guess I do have a grounded load.
3) Correct, the resistor should be for a gain of 100 V/V - and that would be 500k - but I had odd results while simulation and I brought it down to 390k. Probably a point to test in the real circuit.

Comment: changing my circuit to [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13255863/ans2_sch1.png) I end with results in simulation as [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13255863/ans2_1.png). If I merge the answer of scorpdaddy and adjust the open loop gain to >=14 (13*0.01*100*1 = 13 V/V process gain and 4.5V Vgate/Verror = 178 V/V --> 178/13=14) I end with R8 = 180k and the follwing [output](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13255863/ans2_2.png). Seems the issue with negative rail tension is solved, but the controller is not working properly yet. Maybe I have to put the INA168 back?!

Comment: Put 1 nF across R8.

Comment: I tried your 1nF and ended with a 1.5nF. After adding a buffer after my "DAC" I had [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13255863/ans1_sch1.png). It is finally producing me results I can live with(Step [1V](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13255863/trans_1.png) and [80m](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13255863/trans_80m.png)). Just for my understanding: What I did is to switch off Kp for all signals over 1/10k*1.5nF = 66.7kHz, correct? So I did an [Bode plot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13255863/bode.png) - do I risk any instability anywhere?

Comment: @schiggn - Oh yes, if you note the different delays between your two steps, this says that phase depends on amplitude as well as frequency. You'll want to do a lot of testing. Make sure you test the entire range of command voltages.

Comment: I saw the timedifferences, yes. And what I also realised is a ~70mA [offset](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13255863/offset.png) after the a steady state is approacched. Any idea how to correct that / compensate and/or where that comes from?

Comment: @schiggn - It's pretty simple. The current sense amplifier needs very low input offset voltage. A 1 mV offset is equivalent to 100 mA (E = iR, right?). And the LM8272 is grossly unsuited to the task, since it can have as much as 7 mV of offset. Your simulator is providing a "representative" voltage offset. And before you suggest it, forget using an INA168. Don't even think about it. Unless you need a grounded load, it will just add complexity to your circuit, since you'll still need to invert the current measurement to produce an error signal.

Comment: Oh - I didnt considered the Offset voltage. I will have a look at the "bible" (Horowitz's art of electronics) to find a replacement part. And since I only need up to 3A, I can also replace Rshunt with a 0R1 1W to have better precision.

Comment: @schiggn - Also be aware that the I section is a potential source of instability. You'd do well to replace R4 with a 5k/5nF/5k T, especially if you expect to provide control inputs which have high slew rates, such as a DAC.